# QTableView: endMoveRows in model resets horizontal header sizes

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, qtableview

I'm trying to implement drag'n'drop reordering of rows in a `QTableView`.

The operation needs to actually reorder the underlying data, therefore reordering the vertical header rows doesn't seem like a good solution.

I instead opted for the underlying model to handle this by providing the row indices in its `mimeData` function and accepting this list in `dropMimeData`. In the `dropMimeData` function, I use the `beginMoveRows` and `endMoveRows` to move individual rows visually, in addition to moving the underlying data. This approach seems to work, with only one shortcoming: as soon as I call `endMoveRows`, the `QTableView`'s horizontal header resets all its section sizes to defaults.

Am I missing something I need to do, or is this a bug in Qt (or even intended behavior)? Is there any other way to handle drag'n'drop reordering?

Here is a simplified piece of code that shows the same behavior:

```
class Model: public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    Model():
        m_Items({"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"})
    {
    }

    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex & a_Parent, int a_Role) const override
    {
        return QString("%1 - %2").arg(m_Items[a_Parent.row()]).arg(a_Parent.column());
    }

    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex & a_Parent) const override
    {
        return m_Items.count();
    }

    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex & a_Parent) const override
    {
        return 4;
    }

    void moveNow()
    {
        // Moves the last row as the 3rd row:
        auto count = m_Items.count();
        beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), count, count, QModelIndex(), 2);
        m_Items.insert(2, m_Items.last());
        m_Items.pop_back();
        endMoveRows();
    }

protected:
    QStringList m_Items;
};

static Model g_Model;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // "ui" created by QtCreator, has a "tableView" and a "pushButton"
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(&g_Model);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->resizeSection(0, 200);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->resizeSection(1, 100);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->resizeSection(2, 50);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->resizeSection(3, 80);

    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
        [this]()
        {
            // Outputs 200 on first click
            qDebug() << ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->sectionSize(0);

            g_Model.moveNow();

            // Outputs 100
            qDebug() << ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->sectionSize(0);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that calling `emit layoutAboutToBeChanged()` just before the move operation fixes the issue:

```
void moveNow()
{
    emit layoutAboutToBeChanged();
    auto count = m_Items.count();
    beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), count, count, QModelIndex(), 2);
    m_Items.insert(2, m_Items.last());
    m_Items.pop_back();
    endMoveRows();
}
```

This seems to contradict the documentation for `beginMoveRows`, which indicates that it is a replacement for calling this function. Also there must *not* be a matching `emit layoutChanged()` after `endMoveRows`, otherwise the columns are, again, reset.

This all together leads me to believe it's an actual bug in Qt.